# Mysql fetch values from cursor into dynamically

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER t1_trigger BEFORE DELETE ON  t1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
```

-- Declaration
    DECLARE str VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE c1 VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE c2 VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE c3 VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE x int ;
    DECLARE var VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT "var";
    DECLARE i_counter INT DEFAULT 1;

`-- Find the number of columns of a table.
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR select count(*) from information_schema.columns where table_schema='plsqls' and table_name='t1';

-- Get the Column values of table
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.id =     OLD.ID;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

-- Create Dynamic Variables of a table
OPEN cur1;
     FETCH cur1 INTO x;   
         while i_counter < x DO
            SET str =CONCAT(str,CONCAT(var,i_counter,','));
            SET i_counter=i_counter+1;
         end while;
CLOSE cur1;  

-- Assign the coulmn values to the dynamic variables.
-- Here i get the column names instead of column values.
OPEN cur;
    ins_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO str;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE ins_loop;
        END IF;          
        INSERT INTO t1_log VALUES (null, str);
    END LOOP;
   CLOSE cur; 
 END;$$`

Question :
Here THE PROBLEM WE COULD NOT FETCH THE 'str' DYNAMICALLY.
when i'm deleting the table (t1) But i am facing the below the error is 'Incorrect number of FETCH variables'. –

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);      
    INSERT INTO t1 (`id`,`name`,`rank`) values('','ram','1st'),('','ganesh','2nd'),('','dinesh','1nd'),('','guru','2nd'),('','kumar','3nd'),('','raja','2nd'),('','selvi','1nd');

Answer (score 0):

The error you got is **'Incorrect number of FETCH variables'.**
This is because you are selecting all columns from table `t1` as
    `DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.id =     OLD.ID;`)
but fetching only 1 value as
    `FETCH cur INTO str;`

Solution

1. Either select the column you want using the cursor as
   `DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT` **id** `FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = OLD.ID;`

***OR***

2. Fetch all columns you selected as
   `FETCH cur INTO x, y, z;`